# Get the inserted document _id using callback function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am trying to get the inserted document `_id` from `MongoDB` using a `callback` function in `nodejs` (`expressJS`) but I am getting this error:

> AssignmentDB.save is not a function

Here's my code. Can someone help me how to get `_id` with a callback function to `MongoDB`

```
router.route("/assignment/add").post((req, res) => {
  let assignmentDb = new AssignmentDB(req.body);

    AssignmentDB
    .save(assignmentDb, function(err, records){
      if(err) throw err;
      res.status(200).send(records[0]._id); //should send the inserted documents _id
    });

});
```

This is my `AssignmentDB` model looks like:

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let AssignmentDB = new Schema({
    assignmentName: String,
    assignmentDescription: String,
    courseName: String,
    assignmentDueDate: Date,
    isNewAssignment: Boolean    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('AssignmentDB', AssignmentDB, 'AssignmentDB');
```

Comment: This: _Can someone help me how to get _id with a callback function to MongoDB_ - No, because your problem is understanding that `AssignmentDB` isn't what you think it is. Show us how `AssignmentDB` is created or where it lives.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I updated the code. Can you have a look?

Comment: Change `AssignmentDB.save(...)` to `assignmentDB.save(...)`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn now it gives the error **Cannot read property '_id' of undefined**

Comment: Progress! That means `records` is empty, which in turn means `assignmentDB` doesn't have any records, which in turn means the `req` parameter does not contain the data necessary to create the record in the first place. You'll need to make sure your POST includes the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

change your router code like this

```
router.route("/assignment/add").post((req, res) => {
  let assignmentDb = new AssignmentDB(req.body);
    assignmentDb.save(function(err, record){
      if(err) throw err;
      res.status(200).send(record._id); //should send the inserted documents _id
    });

});
```

Save method will return saved record as an object not as an array of objects. Also, call save method on Model instance.

Below is sample example to save a record in MongoDB

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// make a connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tutorialkart');

// get reference to database
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("Connection Successful!");

    // define Schema
    var BookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      price: Number,
      quantity: Number
    });

    // compile schema to model
    var Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema, 'bookstore');

    // a document instance
    var book = new Book({ name: 'Introduction to Mongoose', price: 10, quantity: 25 });

    // save model to database
    book.save(function (err, book) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(book + " saved to bookstore.");
    });

});
```